# Cannot create ofstream file in correct directory using Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am currently doing some homework on Runge Kutta methods am trying to create a file holding my data. I've run my code on different systems and know the code works, but on my current Windows OS I cannot seem to create a file within my program's directory. I've tried entering the direct path to my project as the file name as well as running my code as administrator. No antivirus to interfere with my program either.

My file was created, once, in C:\ but I cannot seem to recreate it again. My path is such:

C:\Users\zacha\OneDrive\Desktop\FCM2\FCMII_HW1\FCMII_HW1\

I am assuming there's some problem here with Visual Studio or the fact I'm going through OneDrive. God, I need to switch to Linux. Any help would be appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "rungekutta.h"
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("C:\\Users\\zacha\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\FCM2\\FCMII_HW1\\FCMII_HW1\\runge_kutta.txt", 
    std::ios::out);
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "Open" << std::endl;
    }
    if (!myfile.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "*** error: could not open output file\n";
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N + 1; i++)
    {
        myfile << do_stuff;
    }
    myfile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

No compile errors, no run time errors. Only the message displayed by

```
if(!myfile.is_open())
```

Comment: You could try calling `GetLastError` after `open` fails.  This should tell you why `open` is failing. Alternatively, look at `errno`.

Comment: The code looks fine (though you don't need to specify `std::ios::out` explicitly, `std::ofstream` handles that for you). So, most likely, you simply don't have permission to access the folder/file in question, or it is offline (OneDrive is remote storage, after all). If you use the Win32 `CreateFile()` API directly, you can then use `GetLastError()` to get the reason why the create is failing (`std::ofstream` is not guaranteed to preserve the error code, hence the suggestion to use `CreateFile()` directly).

Comment: Is there a reason why you check whether `myfile` is open twice? Wouldn't an `else` statement simplify the code?

Comment: With sysinternals processmonitor you can check what file access your program is doing and what the result is. It will show you when there are access denied problems or path/file not found problems.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any errors while looking at the code, For sure it's a permission issue, try changing the path for the file from the "OneDrive" directory and save it locally instead of storing it in a remote location.

Also, you can improve your code :

instead of :

```
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    std::cout << "Open" << std::endl;
}
if (!myfile.is_open())
{
    std::cerr << "*** error: could not open output file\n";
}
```

use:

```
if (!myfile)
{
    std::cerr << "*** error: could not open output file\n";
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Open" << std::endl;
}
```

As the below code is already doing that job for you.

```
myfile.open("C:\\Users\\zacha\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\FCM2\\FCMII_HW1\\FCMII_HW1\\runge_kutta.txt", 
std::ios::out);
```

Comment: I changed my directory to just C:\\, but I still get the error condition. I'm a mathematics student, so CS is not my forte... if C:\\ isn't local then is there a path you'd recommend? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you create a new folder on D drive or E drive to store your data? One-Drive is a personal cloud storage. Storing data on your own disk is more secure.